# Exchange Hub Transport Rule Ignored for local NDR reports

Tags: exchange-2007

I am trying to setup a Hub Transport Rule in Exchange 2007 to redirect NDR reports sent to a specific company email address to a separate "undeliverable" mailbox. I do not want to redirect all NDRs for all mailboxes... just NDRs sent to this address. The transport rule is as follows:

> Apply rule to messages: Sent to
>   info@company.com and when the Subject field
>   contains: "Delivery Delayed" or
>   "Undeliverable" redirect the message
>   to undeliverable@company.com

This rule works when I send a test message internally with the specified words in the subject. It also works for external emails that contain those subjects. However, for messages generated internally and sent locally via the Microsoft Exchange email address (MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@company.com) the transport rules do not appear to be applied.

My questions are:

- Is the local Microsoft Exchange sender excluded from Hub Transport Rules?
- Are there other ways to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Microsoft Exhange 2010 docs:

> System messages are not processed by rules agents.

[link text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124703(EXCHG.140).aspx)

This information is not listed in the equivalent docs for 2007, but I assume 2007 has the same limitations. Unfortunately it looks like our desired rules are impossible to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official word from Microsoft.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124703(v=exchg.80).aspx

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.